# Random vector with a random number of entries

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let's say I roll an $N$-sided die, and read off the number showing, $n$.  I then draw $n$ random numbers, $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.  The result is a sort of random vector $A = (n;x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ that has a random number of entries.  What is the proper way to model this as a random variable, i.e. how should I define my range probability space in a reasonable way so that I can start writing down expressions involving $\text{pr}(A)$?  Assuning WLOG that N is infinite (I'm thinking mostly of $n$ being Poisson distributed), I want to somehow use the infinite product

$$
\mathbb{N}\times \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}^2\times \cdots 
$$
but something seems wrong about that.

Comment: You can think of this also as $\mathbb N\times R^{\mathbb N}$ where you simply take the first (or any) $n$ coordinates from an element of $R^{\mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where the "infinite" part comes in. The way you describe it, you pick a random vector from $$\mathbb R\cup\mathbb R^2\cup\cdots\cup \mathbb R^N$$

Where you have a $\frac1N$ probability of selecting a vector from $\mathbb R$, the same probability for selecting a vector $\mathbb R^2$ and so on.

You didn't specify how you select the random numbers $x_i$ after determining $n$, but let's assume you select them uniformly from the interval $(0,1)$. In that case, the probability of selecting a $1$-dimensional vector between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{N}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Right, sorry - poorly phrased question. I meant to then state that $N$ can be infinite (I.e. $n$ is a discrete RV e.g. Poisson)

Comment: @icurays1 Then yes, you have an infinite union (not product!), and instead of $\frac{1}{N}\cdot \frac16$, the answer to my example would be $P(N=1)\cdot \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: See edited question. So, more appropriate might be $\Bbb{N}\times\cup_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{R}^n$...?

Comment: @icurays1 Makes sense to me, yes

Comment: Cool, thanks. My intuition failed me here for some reason.